# Make CSS animation not restart

Tags: html, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

Im writing a website with a zooming animation on a sphere at start, I also have a shake animation at hovering but when I'm done hovering the zoom animation starts. So I need help with some code to stop the animation from restarting after hover.

```
@keyframes aBackground {
0% { background-size: 100%; }
100% { background-size: 110% }
}
   .logo:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a working example of all he code on a site like jsfiddle. As Jay answered, animation-iteration-count might be helpful - but the default setting for that property is 1 and you don't seem to be using it above.

Comment: the thing is that the zoom animation only plays once but when I hover and stop hover it plays again

Comment: maybe `animation-play-state: paused;` might help

Comment: that was my first thought to but didn't help

Comment: @HugoAugustsson Maybe when you hover you would add a class via javascript (like `.pause`) then write a style for that class with just the `animation-play-state: paused;` style. But I might be mis-understanding your problem. You should create a demo of your problem

Comment: I can record the problem for you

Comment: funny, your code do not match on animation name. ....  make a working snippet to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `animation-iteration-count`

Comment: if you add `animation-iteration-count: 1;` to your zooming animation it still restarts after you hover?